# Freeze flash movie

Tags: c++, flash, delphi, winapi

I have a flash movie loaded into my browser.Is there any way that i can pause it and then resume it.I tryed SuspendThread() for all the browser threads but the movie won't freeze

Comment: heh, a tag chaos. actually closest approach toward this problem will be JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What browser are you using? I know that Firefox runs Flash in a separate process, called `plugin-container.exe`.

Also, suspending a multimedia thread is not usually a good idea.  If you suspend the thread feeding the sound card, you'll throw your audio into an endless loop that's *very* annoying!

Comment: i want to make a game trainer for a flash browser game i found out that chrome is creating a separate process to handle with flash i am able to freeze it now but the game contains a clock wich doesn't freeze so it's usless.